# Vocal fry plus? Does this John Lennon singing style have a name?

Tags: voice, styles, vocal-fry

I recently learned the term "vocal fry" from an online singing lesson on pop singing styles. Now that I know what it is, I should think this is an effect instantly familiar to most people, even if they hadn't realized it had a name, as it occurs quite frequently as a means of expression in pop and related singing styles.

My question is about a possible variant of vocal fry, but much stronger and with a kind of overblown, almost Dalek-like effect that I've often noticed in John Lennon's vocals. I would like to know if this effect has a name.

Examples can be heard in Bungalow Bill, at the following points on [this YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J39DC9t0I5o):

```
0:30 "always took his mum" (second syllable of "always")
1:40 "if to kill was not a sin" (the word "kill")
1:49 "his mummy butted in" ("mummy")
```

Comment: I actually wonder whether it's an artifact of recording rather than a vocal technique—a little tape warble or something?

Comment: Sounds like John being John to me. I doubt he ever gave a thought to whether it had a name or not.

Comment: I've made this sound before.  I made that sound today, actually.  I'm no vocalist, so I can't describe it well or do it reliably, but... Here's how I arrived at it.  I was attempting to sing higher notes than I am comfortable with by using a "light" chest voice, i.e. less pressure and more air, slightly airy tone, and trying to use the minimum amount of effort from the muscles up in the throat.  So, almost opposite of "squeezing" out high notes.  If you know how to I can comfortably sing up to around G4 ish, and I got this sound around B4.

Comment: I'd say it feels like a fry scream, but I don't even know if my "fry scream" is actually a fry  scream.  But just a little bit of that "squishing the vocal folds together" feeling does help this sound come out.

Comment: Thanks all for the interesting thoughts so far! Think I'll add Lennon's name to the title in case it catches any eyes that might not have bothered to read it yet.